# paralleling switching regulators

Tags: boost

If one has to design a boost power supply that should generate high output current, it can be a solution to parallel multiple boosters and connect their output nodes to each other. Does this approach have any problems?

Many booster ICs have SYNC pins so that multiple regulators can be synchronized with each other using an external clock generator. The boosters would have ripples in the output voltage, but the amplitude should be small.

I know that there is a method called "load sharing" or "current sharing". But I wonder why it is needed.

Comment: Using this approach of paralleling regulated power supplies there is a chance that the control circuits influence each other, leading to unwanted oscillations.

Comment: @joeelectro Do you mean the external control circuit, or internal circuits in the chips?

Comment: This is something you can do, but it requires special considerations that I'm not familiar enough with to advise on.

Comment: @Nownuri No, the internal control circuits. If the circuits are identical the time constants in the controllers are also identical. They might (and probably will) interfere which each other. For this kind of applications you'd need power supplies that can work in a master (multi-)slave configuration.

Comment: @joeelectro I couldn't think about the time constant. Thank you for your explanation and for proposing a solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to do, but it is not as simple as you think.

First comes the switching frequency. If you have several regulators interacting, beat frequencies and resonances can occur. As you mention some modules/regulators have synchronization inputs and/or outputs that would fix this issue.

Then comes load sharing. Whatever module has the highest output voltage will take the brunt of the load while the other regulators attempt to reduce their output. A small series resistor on each might help equalize the loads somewhat, but this will waste power and reduce load regulation.

And last, but most importantly, comes regulation feedback loop stability. The interaction of multiple similar feedback loops fighting with each other, makes an overall unstable and chaotic system very likely, which could result on EMC problems, output oscillation problems, or even the destruction of the modules themselves or the attached circuitry.

Some modules/regulators have been designed to be ganged together. These will normally have a “share” connection that allows their control algorithms to cooperate for equally sharing the load. Others can be made to cooperate with a vendor-approved method that is provided in their datasheets.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! I wanted to learn more about your second point. The output voltages of the converters will be fixed within some error. When these converters have different output current initially, then after the time how does one keeps taking most of the load?

Comment: Because the output tolerance is an error that always remains. It can only be fixed by changing components. One regulator will always be trying to raise the voltage while the others are trying to lower it.

Comment: So the differences in the output voltages of the converters are not big, but within the tolerance? Although it's not 1/N, one converter doesn't take 50% or more of the total output current?

Comment: It depends on how good is their own load regulation. But if these are well-designed, a 1% voltage difference could mean that one regulator takes 100% of the load (at least until its own current limit is reached).

Comment: The synchronization Nownuri referred to is for the switching, not the control/feedback. If there is a 'share' connection, then its ok to use them in parallel.

Comment: @joeelectro as long as the datasheet guidelines for the use of the share connections are followed, of course.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Would there be a good search keyword to learn about the phenomena that 1% voltage difference causes large difference in the output currents? Unfortunately from textbook I find only explanation of single booster.

Comment: @Nownuri **uneven current sharing** is a well-understood phenomena that is not exclusive to power regulators. It arises whenever any set of devices are put in parallel to share a load. For example, it is well known that FETs share current better than bipolars, as their gain goes down with temperature. Using **load-balancing resistors** is necessary with bipolars, but could be omitted with FETs. Switching devices introduce even more complications.

Comment: I'm sorry that I still couldn't find an analytical explanation. When one output voltage is higher than the others, then what happens to the lower output voltage regulators? Do they stop generating current, even though their diodes are not reverse biased?

Comment: @Nownuri it depends on the design of the regulator. It would reduce its output current up to the point of stopping it, and will try to sink current if possible. The analysis is simple, all of the gain equations and load regulation reduce to a thevenin equivalent with a small 10’s of mohm resistance. Put together several thevenin equivalents with different voltages and a large load and see what happens.